# Rotating an image *before* rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'd like to rotate a landscape image to appear in a portrait orientation in a 2 panel view. The original landscape image will still be used in a single panel view- so altering the original file isn't an option.

The issue is that the size of an image is set before it is rotated- so the DOM spaces things according to the 'pre-rotated' state. Is there any way to

1. **Rotate image orientation in js** (i'd prefer not to use a library, but am willing)
2. **Size elements in a 'post rotated' state?**

Below is my current code(only containing the rotated image in 2 panel view)- followed by a link to more detailed codepen example (includes more context to desired render)

If it helps: I'm working in React on the actual project.

```css
.spread {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 250px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.frame {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  align-self: center;
}

.portrait {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.ldsc {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 312px;
  min-width: 298px;
}

.ldsc.port {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="spread">
  <div class="frame port">
    <img class="ldsc port" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="portraitImg" />
  </div>
  <div class="frame port">
    <img class="portrait" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="portraitImg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[Try It!](https://codepen.io/knapptr/pen/bGdaqdZ)

Answer (score 1):

1. Javascript can rotate the image in 2 ways: with css and inside a canvas. The first solution is similar to yours, and second is pretty tricky, and is not a good for your case.
2. Second solution is pretty possible.
3. There can be a different solution, setting the image as the background to a square div, `background-position:contain`. And placing the square div into your vertical panel. Basically, a pure css.

Comment: Would this be 'best practice' for an image that is considered content? I have been working with <img> tags because the 'pages' are the real content of the page.

Comment: SEO is a different question. Second solution would be the best for it by default, and the third one can have a workaround like that: https://schema.org/ImageObject, Example 2, use <meta> instead of <img> and `content` instead of `src`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. It will work as long as your other images proportions stays the same. Just add it to the end of your css, or replace `.ldsc.port{...`

```css
.ldsc.port{
    transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.5);
}
.frame.port {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This just crops the image to its parent container- but then a lot of the image isnt visible- and the parent container still sizes to the original landscape size. (see the [codepen](https://codepen.io/knapptr/pen/bGdaqdZ) for an example)